# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden with headers

Tags: python, json, session, python-requests, urllib

I have been doing scraping for a while, but never seen this problem without the fixed I have used working. I am trying to scrape "https://www.coolbet.com/s/sbgate/sports/recommendations/turnover?country=NO&isLive=false&language=en&layout=EUROPEAN" but havent been able to work around the "HTTP Error 403". Normally changing the headers does wonders, but not in this case.
I am starting to think it might be a cookie problem, but open for suggestion and fixes.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
reg_url = "https://www.coolbet.com/s/sbgate/sports/fo-category/?categoryId=62&country=NO&isMobile=0&language=en&layout=EUROPEAN&limit=15"
req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 
html = urlopen(req).read() 
print(html)
```

I have also tried using "import requests"

Comment: This error has nothing to do with your scraper, the web server isn't allowing access to this page. 
"The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. This status is similar to 401 , but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference"

Comment: Is there a way to get around this error?